# jquery gt() get current index

Tags: jquery

I'm using `gt()` to add columns to a table.

I need to use the row number and the column number to build the cell id.

Getting the column number is straightforward:

```
var c = $("#gridLayout tr:first td").length;
```

but how can I get the current index from gt() for the row number?

```
$("#gridLayout tr:gt(0)").append('<td>.......</td>');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to use the built in index parameter for `.each()`.

This lets you get an index number *without* having to call another method.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/8V4AY/

```
   // Reference index --------------v
$("#gridLayout tr").each(function( idx ) {
       // idx contains the current index number,
       //    without having to call another method

     $(this).append('<td>.......</td>');
});
```

If you were going to skip the first row:

```
$("#gridLayout tr:gt(0)")...
```

you could adjust the `idx` by 1 if you need

```
idx++;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8V4AY/1/

Comment: Touche Patrick! I do believe your solution is more elegant - you get my vote.

Comment: @Hurns - Thanks for the vote. :o) In all honesty, your solution was the first that came to mind, so when you beat me to it, I had to think of something else. Overall, I think this may be a little quicker.

Comment: Great thanks - you get the tick for introducing me to jsfiddle!

Answer (score 2):

Im not really sure what your goal here is but something similar to the following would return the row index and append whatever contents:

```
$('#gridlayout tr').each( function() {
    $(this).append('<td> Things.... </td>');
    alert($(this).index());
})
```

If you post some more details I will gladly provide further info.